# ambiguous redirect bash from pipes

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin

I want to delete some docker images w/ a redirection of my previouse command.

```
 docker images | grep "2 months ago" | grep -v "mailcow" | awk '{print$3}'
```

just redirect via "<" to `docker image rm` turns out *ambiguous redirect*

also  `docker image rm $(docker images | grep "2 month ago" | grep -v "mailcow" | awk '{print $3}')` does not work.

Any ideas to redirect stdout to stdin?

Answer (score 1):

From Docker documentation with [`docker image prune [OPTIONS]`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) and using its supported filters (`until` filter here) you can get what you need:

following example ***will delete all images*** that created more than 60 days (1440h) ago:

**Do not run this command if you don't know what it does**

```
docker image prune -a --force --filter "until=1440h"
```